# Issue in simultaneous login of web app and sitefinity

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I have integrated sitefinity with my web application.
I am logged in my sitefinity login page by typing the follwing url

```
https://localhost:6278/Sitefinity/Login?ReturnUrl=/sitefinity
```

As soon as I login my sitefinity cookies are set.

Now , in the same browser when I am trying to login to my web application 
https://localhost:6278/Main/

Instead  of showing me the default signinpage it is redirecting me to
`https://localhost:6278/`  page.

**But if I ma not logged in using sitefinity initially** it is working as expected i.e. first it redirects me to signinpage and as soon as i enter my credentials it redirect me to Main page.

I have used forms authentication .
Please assist me.

Comment: You can sign-in using only 1 ID in a browser. Have you ever tried signing into facebook once you are already signed in? This behaviour is desirable as otherwise you would have to sign in every time you need to open something in a new tab.

Comment: The issue is , if I am logged in on sitefinity and then try to access my web application it should redirect me to the login page of web application.
FYI..I have implemented forms authentication where as FB uses claims based authentication

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of authentication you employ. Thumb rule is you can't sign-in to a website using 2 different ID's. This makes perfect sense. Imagine you are signed-in in 2 different browser tabs using different ID's. Then you open third tab and type the address of application. How can browser decide which ID you should be signed-in in the third tab

Comment: @It'satrap is right - once you are authenticated to the server in one browser - then you are authenticated in all tabs/windows as they share the same auth cookies (tokens, etc.). The server does not know (care) from which browser window your request is coming - he only needs to know what cookies are sent with the request.